# Stopping the network-dispatcher service due to slow boot because the GUI has one of its own, a viable option?

Tags: networking, network-manager, services

On a reddit post on r/Ubuntu titled [Short guide to improve slow boot on Ubuntu (>=18.04)](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/clu0lj/short_guide_to_improve_slow_boot_on_ubuntu_1804/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) one of the options provided is:

> **Disable networkd services**: If you are not a system admin you don't need this. Gui uses network-manger (and it has it's own dispatcher) anyway.

And the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove networkd-dispatcher
sudo systemctl stop systemd-networkd.service
sudo systemctl disable systemd-networkd.service
```

In my case `network-dispatcher` service is also causing slow boot around 20 sec but I was not able to understand the reason given above simply stopping it, are there any downsides to the above mentioned suggestion I should be aware of?

Pointers and resources would be great!

Comment: I would strongly suggest not following one of these nefarious "disable everything" reddit guides.  If you have more than one question, you should ask them separately.  We use a Q&A format to keep the site organized.

Comment: I would be very careful about removing any network program/service.   Did that many years ago when having problems.  Wanted to remove and then install again.  Won't do that again.

Comment: @Nmath I have formatted the whole question again to ask for one specific thing, you can have a look now.

Comment: Remember that your computer is capable of doing more than one thing at a time.  Every single one of these services has a purpose, and the purpose isn't to annoy you or to slow down your system, despite what some redditors may claim.  Does that really make sense when you really think about it? Most of these services make your computer faster when it is most needed.  [This is what `networkd-dispatcher` does](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/networkd-dispatcher.8.html).  I suggest that you leave this and other BG processes alone.

Comment: I think the question is relevant to desktop environments where (as opposed to server environments) networking is almost always managed by `NetworkManger.service`. Therefore `systemd-networkd.service` is kept disabled by default. Then why is even `networkd-dispatcher.service` running when, in fact, `NetworkManager-dispatcher.service` is already enabled and doing the [former's job](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/networkd-dispatcher.8.html)? Hence it would be good to know whether the service mentioned in the question really is redundant when `NetworkManger` is running.